# How to replace a text with another in Perl

Tags: text-processing, perl

Using `tr` command I want to convert `Hello` into `Hii`.
My command was:

```
$_="Hello";
print;
tr/Hello/Hi/;
print;
```

But the result was `Hiiii`. What did I do wrong?
What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To replace `Hello`by `Hii` you could use:

```
s/Hello/Hii/
```

`tr` works different. Using `tr` both character sequences are handled as lists. The first character of the first list is replaced by the first character of the second list. So, `H` is replaced by `H`, `e` is replaced by `i` and so on.